# Is there anything like bottom transparent folder drawer as right workspace drawer?

Tags: gnome, package-management, directory, workspaces, extension

Sometimes we keep lots of folders on the desktop and it makes the desktop layout messy. It would have been great, if there were anything like bottom a folder drawer like the right side workspace drawer, where we could arrange all important folders in rows.
If you know any package or extension like this, please let me know. If there is nothing like this, please tell me how I can send this feature request to Ubuntu.
Thanks to all!

Comment: Can you give an example of this?  Have you tried different desktop environments? (Try using a live session)

Comment: No, I didn't see it anywhere. It's just my thought.